# ApiClient - fetch returns [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I have an apiClient file which contains the generic get method below:

```
export const API_URL = 'https://localhost:40000';

const query = async <T>(request: RequestInfo, options?: RequestInit): Promise<T> => {
  return fetch(request, options).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw response;
    }
    return response.json();
  });
};

export const get = async <T>(url: string): Promise<T> =>
  query(`${API_URL}${url}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
  });
```

In my services, I have a function that calls the get method (fetch) and takes a string URL.

```
const getAllProjects = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await get<Response>('/Projects');
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      const projects = await jsonData.data;
      return projects;
    }
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

However, the issue I am facing is when I call the query method in the generic get method, it returns [object Object]. I have tried to pass in a string URL and replace it with `${API_URL}${url}` but this also returned the same outcome.

Comment: You seem to calling the `.json` method inside *and outside* of your `query` function, which doesn't make sense. Also you're using `.then` in an `async` method, which isn't necessarily _wrong_ but suggests the code hasn't been thought through.

Comment: GET requests have no request body and therefore, need no content-type header

Comment: To elaborate on @jonrsharpe's comment, `get` already does the work unmarshalling data from the response. All you need in `getAllProjects` is `const jsonData = await get<Response>("/Projects")`

Comment: Thank you all, following these fixes my code is now working!!